# Forwarding a url to an IP plesk

Tags: hosting, plesk

Im trying to forward a subdomain to an IP address in Parallels Plesk,

Ive selected the relevant domain, gone to DNS settings and created and A record with the name im wanting to point and the IP address.

E.g

webmail.domain.net to the IP address

I then updated the changes.

But when I try to visit the address the server times out, is there something I missed?

Many Thanks

Mark

Comment: By "url" do you mean "hostname"?

Comment: What times out? DNS resolution? Accessing whatever service you are trying to access?

Comment: Hi Quentin, Yes sorry I mean hostname. When I try to access the subdomain in the broswer so webmail.domain.net I get the connection has time out as the connection is taking too long to respond

Comment: Hmm... Have you check your binding on IIS? Can you ping it? what is the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Click Add Record
Select A Record
Enter ABC on first box
Enter IP on second box
Click Ok
Click Update
and then access the abc.yourdomain.com

See the result also some how on same location ISP did not cached the Current IP caching so please use always ping.eu to check IP redirection has been done or still not resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this now; someone had put a wildcard A record in which was overriding all the changes I made.